# How to Display count of subscribers for particular speaker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display count of subscribers for particular speaker in my index page. I didnt do anything in my route because i am simply looping in my index page. I have working listenerspeakers association.  In my pages controller i have

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @messages = Message.all.order("created_at DESC")

    @speakers = Speaker.all
    @sub = ListenersSpeakers.all


  end

end
```

in my view i try to loop and insert this code but it doesnt work.

```
<% @sub.each do |sub| %>
<%= @sub.speaker.count %>&nbsp;Subscribers</span>
<% end %>
```

my model

```
class ListenersSpeakers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listener
  belongs_to :speaker
end
```

Update
 my Speaker model has

```
has_many :listeners_speakers,  class_name: 'ListenersSpeakers'
```

Comment: There's no need to explicitly declare a intermediate relationship class ListenersSpeakers with a simple relationship like listener belongs_to speaker, and speaker has_many listeners.  Is there a reason you've chosen to go this route in your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assume that in the `Speaker` model, it `has_many :listener_speakers` like:

```
class Speaker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listener_speakers
end
```

You can then use

```
@sub.speaker.listener_speakers.count
```

in the view to get the number of listeners.

Not related to the question, but you may also want to consider adding a:

```
has_many :listeners, through: :listener_speakers
```

as that may eventually prove useful.

Comment: when i insert @sub.speaker.listener_speakers.count or @sub.speakers.listener_speakers.count, i get an error undefined method `speakers' .  My Speaker model has has_many :listeners_speakers,  class_name: 'ListenersSpeakers'.  What else could it be? Thanks

Comment: WHen i try to add variable @speaker = Speaker.find(params[:id]) i get an error can not find speaker with ID

Comment: I do have this like in my speaker model has_many :listeners, through: :listeners_speakers

Comment: ok, i figure out i simpy put <%= speaker.listeners_speakers.count %> and it showed right number of subscribes.  Thanks